# In Snowflake-SQLAlchemy, how do I use the result metadata? Specifically, how do I get the data types of the result set?

Tags: sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Given the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(
'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/{database}/{schema}?warehouse={warehouse}&role={role}'.format(
user=user_config.snowflake_credentials['username'],
password=user_config.snowflake_credentials['password'],
account='turnkeyvr.us-east-1',
database=database,
schema=schema,
warehouse=warehouse,
role=role
)
)
conn = self.engine.connect()
sql = """
select
    1 as my_int,
    current_date as my_date
"""
results = conn.execute(sql)
```

results will be an object of type sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy. It has a member _metadata, which has functions that execute during init that compile lots of metadata from different sources. I can't seem to figure out how to access any of that metadata. The [docs](https://kite.com/python/docs/sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy) seem to have a lot of blank pages, and don't seem to have any information on this. Is getting the datatypes of the columns in the result set a feature that hasn't been implemented yet? Am I missing something? Note that I am not talking about inspecting existing tables, which is covered [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.get_columns), but rather the result set of a query. All help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I found a way to get the data types, below. I am still interested in the other metadata elements available, and how the SQLAlchemy ResultMetaData object improves on what Snowflake provides, so I will leave the question open for a while.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is only a partial answer, but it gets me what I need. I will leave the question open so that others can answer more completely and hopefully help others.

When I do `results = conn.execute(sql)`, the results object is of a type sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy, as noted in the question above. results.cursor is an object of type snowflake.connector.cursor.SnowflakeCursor. The docs for that are on the Snowflake website [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#object-cursor). This Cursor object has a member called description, which is a list of tuples with metadata information. The documentation on this is almost nonexistent, but I found [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#type-codes). Looking at the description I have for a boolean column I selected I see `('IS_DELETED', 13, None, None, None, None, True)`. The first entry is clearly the column name, as is documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#retrieving-column-metadata). I don't know what the other entries in the tuple mean, but the second entry is the type_code for boolean, so clearly that indicates the datatype of the column.

Here is some code to iterate through your column names and datatypes:

```
snowflake_datatype_codes = {
0: 'NUMBER',
1: 'FLOAT',
2: 'TEXT',
3: 'DATE',
4: 'TIMESTAMP',
5: 'VARIANT',
6: 'TIMESTAMP_LTZ',
7: 'TIMESTAMP_TZ',
8: 'TIMESTAMP_NTZ',
9: 'OBJECT',
10: 'ARRAY',
11: 'BINARY',
12: 'TIME',
13: 'BOOLEAN'
}

for entry in results.cursor.description:
    print(entry[0]+': '+snowflake_datatype_codes[entry[1]])
```

Clearly this lacks some information, such as the scale and precision of the number fields, but it appears this is all Snowflake provides so we will have to make do.

Comment: it looks like they've updated the docs since you last looked. here are the meanings of the items in the tuple: https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-api#description

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved by using [DESCRIBE RESULT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc-result.html):

> **DESCRIBE RESULT**
>
> Describes the columns in the result of a query.

In simplest form:

```
-- here goes query
DESC RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
```

If post-processing is required it could be combined with `RESULT_SCAN`:

```
DESC RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```